# Help me - iOs version Problem

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have iOs version 3.2.3 version. now i have installed 4.2 version in my system but when i open my xcode it shows the previous version of iOs...
Even when i go and edit the project settings, i dont get the 3.2.5 version in the drop down to select.
why this happening...
please help me out

Comment: barbgal, you're not seeing 3.2.5 because that's the Xcode version, not the iOS version. See my answer and the final comment for an explanation. Hope this helps!

Comment: I suppose..This is not a programming related question.. Is it?

Answer (score 1):

That version number is actually the Xcode version number, not the iOS version number. Select "About Xcode" from the Xcode dropdown, and you'll see 3.2.5.

If you want to change the iOS version to the new one (I'm guessing 4.2?) try opening up the Target Info (or the Project Settings), and setting the Base SDK to the version you want. (You can also set the Deployment Target to the minimum version you want to support, as [discussed here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/35023-base-sdk-vs-iphone-os-deployment-target.html).

Once you do this, select the new SDK from the dropdown menu at the top left, and you should be good to go.

Comment: iOS version 3.2.5 doesn't exist, as I mention above. 3.2.5 is the Xcode version number. Possible iOS version numbers are 3.2, 3.2.1, 3.2.2, then we jump to 4.0, as shown here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_version_history#2.2

Comment: Okay, awesome! Looks like you're all set with your update. To be clear, you're not going to see 3.2.5 ever, but that's okay, since the update worked. Does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Please open Xcode then from 
Xcode-> About Xcode ->Version 3.2.5 (Check out the version here)

If its still not showing please check out whether the xcode setup is successfully done. Try rebooting your mac.

**P.S: For Installing Xcode 3.2.5 you need to update your Mac OS to 10.6.5**

Also iOS version number will be 4.2 and not 3.2.5 i.e your iPhone/iPAd version whether be device or simulator.. So in dropdown if you see 4.2 then your setup is done successfully..

hAPPY iCODING...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two installations of SDK and XCode on your machine. This can happen if you have changed the installation location while installing the SDK. Hope that helps.